# application to list the page elements of an url

Tags: http, url

I need to make an application which will access an URL(like http://google.com) and return the time spent to load all elements(images, css, js...) and compare this results with the previous results.

This application need to be a Desktop app, and I will save the informations in a text file ou xml, and use this file do compare with previous results.

I have searched for a similar application, but nothing...

There are some plugins for firefox that list these elements, like Yslow or Firebug, but not what I need.

So, i'm totally lost and I don't know how to start this work?

Exists the possibility of make this application? What language is better for this type of application?

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very objective question, so without you elaborating more on your requirements, you may not get any useful answers.

Some things you would need to answer are: how many URLs you want to check, where are you wanting to store the results (database, files etc), does it need to run on the desktop or on a server etc.

Personally, I like the statistics that cURL gives you - DNS time, connect time, receive time etc - so you could write something in PHP, but as I stress that is personal preference and may not suit your situation.

Comment: Andy,for the first moment, i think to colect the informations I need and then save this in a .txt file ou something like this.

About the application, this application need to be an desktop app.